# CV height, width, channels to channels, height, width

Tags: python, opencv

I am processing an image using OpenCV and its cuda functions in Python.

I have an OpenCV GMat of size (300, 300) and 3 channels. In numpy, that shape would be 300x300x3.

I need to perform in OpenCV the equivalent of the numpy function numpy_array.transpose((2, 0, 1)) and I want to do this on the GPU. In other words, I want channels to be the first axis rather than the last one.

In numpy:

```
numpy_array = np.random.randint(0, 255, (300, 300, 3), dtype='uint8')
... various operations...
numpy_array.transpose((2, 0, 1))
```

In OpenCV - CUDA:

```
gpu_frame = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
gpu_frame.upload(numpy_frame)
...various operations...
# TODO: how to move channels to first axis?
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no straight forward method to do this. To make such memory reorganization on gpu there must be a specific "gpu routine", which opencv doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific transpose operation (changing channels from the fastest changing dimension to the slowest changing dimension) is supported in OpenCV, but I don't think there is `GpuMat` support yet, either in C++ or in python.

To do this with `cv::Mat`, you can use [cv::dnn::blobFromImage](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga29f34df9376379a603acd8df581ac8d7). This is convenient in C++, but less so in python (since you can just use numpy). That said, in python, `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(numpy_array)[0]` is equivalent to `numpy_array.transpose((2, 0, 1))`.

See this [github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16433) for the discussion about an analogous API for `GpuMat`'s.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely subscribe to the GitHub issue